# Why cannot find cudnn.h

Tags: cudnn, caffe2

I installed the cudnn 7.1.2 by anaconda, and then install the coffe2 via anaconda following https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=mac&configuration=prebuilt ,but it reports that cannot find cudnn.h.

The error reports are:

```
In file included from /home/wangqm/anaconda3/conda-bld/caffe2-cuda9.0-cudnn7_1530109091069/work/caffe2/operators/depthwise_3x3_conv_op.cu:1:0:
/home/wangqm/anaconda3/conda-bld/caffe2-cuda9.0-cudnn7_1530109091069/work/caffe2/core/common_cudnn.h:7:19: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMake Error at caffe2_gpu_generated_depthwise_3x3_conv_op.cu.o.Release.cmake:219 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/wangqm/anaconda3/conda-bld/caffe2-cuda9.0-cudnn7_1530109091069/work/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/operators/./caffe2_gpu_generated_depthwise_3x3_conv_op.cu.o


caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/build.make:252: recipe for target 'caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/operators/caffe2_gpu_generated_depthwise_3x3_conv_op.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/operators/caffe2_gpu_generated_depthwise_3x3_conv_op.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1458: recipe for target 'caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Caffe2 expert, but this error means that you do not have the CUDNN library installed.
This means that you are trying to use the CUDA enabled Caffe framework and will want to install CUDA (probably version 9+) with the associated CUDNN libraries.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I have installed the cuda via sudo :D